# Sorting list of big numbers provided in String without calculating their values

Tags: java, sorting, math, factorial, exponential

There is a given list of numbers that are written in string format x^y or z!. For example 1000^1000, 954! 525^419, 89!, 427!, 428^727... x,y,z are random values within interval <0,1000>. The list may contain up to 200 of these formulas. I need to somehow sort this given string list in ascending order based on value of these formulas without calculating the values. How can one check if some factorial is greater than some power number without calculating its value?

Comment: To sort, you need to compare, so you want to be able to compare e.g. `"99!"` and `"42^96"` without actually calculating their values *(which are `9.33e155` and `6.79e155`)*? You can't, because you have nothing to compare, if you don't have the values.

Comment: Exactly! But the thing is, I need somehow to check, which is greater without having these values because there is a certain time limit for the program to complete, and if I would be calculating them, it would not fit into the specified time limit.

Comment: You could compare *approximate* values, if that is acceptable, for better performance. E.g. compare the logarithm of the values: `log(x^y)` = `y * log(x)` and `log(x!)` = [Ramanujan's approximation to factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152342/728090)

Comment: @Andreas You are absolutely right. But may I suggest that there is no need of approximation. You can write `log(x!) = log(x)+log(x-1) + ... + log(1)`. Since you mentioned that z is atmost 1000, you can precompute the cumulative sum till `log(1000)`. Then you can just use any standard sorting algorithm to sort the double values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387090/sorting-list-of-big-numbers-provided-in-string-without-calculating-their-values?noredirect=1#comment119109746_67387090):

> I need somehow to check, which is greater without having these values because there is a certain time limit for the program to complete.

To sort, you do need some kind of value. Since performance is the issue, you may have to calculate *approximate* values.

E.g. calculate the *logarithm* of the values:

- For "power", that's easy: `log(x^y)` = `y * log(x)`
- For "factorial", you can use `log(x!)` = [Ramanujan's approximation to factorial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/152342/728090)

  Alternatively, as [suggested by risingStark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67387090/sorting-list-of-big-numbers-provided-in-string-without-calculating-their-values?noredirect=1#comment119110385_67387090):

  > There is no need of approximation. Use `log(x!)` = `log(x)+log(x-1) + ... + log(1)`. Since `x` is at most 1000, precompute the cumulative sum till `log(1000)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the C++ code for the above problem.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i, n;
    vector<string> arr = {"1000^1000", "954!", "525^419", "89!", "427!", "428^727"};
    n = (int)arr.size();
    vector<pair<double, int> > ans;
    vector<double> calc(1001);

    // Since the maximum number is 1000, Pre-calculating the cumulative log sum
    for(i=2;i<=1000;i++){
        calc[i] = log10(i) + calc[i-1];
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        string temp = arr[i];
        int x = (int)temp.size();
        if(temp[x-1]=='!'){
            int k = stoi(temp.substr(0, x-1));
            ans.push_back({calc[k], i});
        }else{
            int f = temp.find('^');
            int a = stoi(temp.substr(0, f));
            int b = stoi(temp.substr(f+1));
            ans.push_back({b*log10(a), i});
        }
    }
    sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[ans[i].second]<<" ";
    }cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}

void solve(){
    int i, n;
    vector<string> arr = {"1000^1000", "954!", "525^419", "89!", "427!", "428^727"};
    n = (int)arr.size();
    vector<pair<double, int> > ans;
    vector<double> calc(1001);

    // Since the maximum number is 1000, Pre-calculating the cumulative log sum
    for(i=2;i<=1000;i++){
        calc[i] = log10(i) + calc[i-1];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        string temp = arr[i];
        int x = (int)temp.size();
        if(temp[x-1]=='!'){
            int k = stoi(temp.substr(0, x-1));
            ans.push_back({calc[k], i});
        }else{
            int f = temp.find('^');
            int a = stoi(temp.substr(0, f));
            int b = stoi(temp.substr(f+1));
            ans.push_back({b*log10(a), i});
        }
    }
    sort(ans.begin(), ans.end());
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[ans[i].second]<<" ";
    }cout<<endl;
}
```